# ICANHAZ.js render dom element instead of text

Tags: javascript, icanhaz.js

Param:

```
'<div class="someclass">' + somecontent + '</div>' + somecontent2
```

Template:

```
<div>{{ param }}</div>
```

And in browser I have:

```
&lt;div class="someclass"&gt; somecontent &lt;/div&gt;somecontent2
```

How to isolate `.someclass`, that it render as a dom element, not text?

Comment: Somewhere in the process these html characters are escaped. Find where that happend and make it not happen any more.

Answer (score 9):

I think all Html elements are escaped by default.  To return un-escaped Html use the triple mustache:

```
<div>{{{param}}}</div>
```

Comment: can i use mustache without any template? i am thinking to use in html without any template..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using partial templates for this.

```
<script id="main" type="text/html">
<div>{{>partial}}</div>
</script>

<script id="partial" class="partial" type="text/html">
<div class="someclass">{{somecontent}}</div>{{somecontent2}}
</script>
```

Then just call the main template with your data as normal:

```
html = ich.main({
    somecontent: 'content',
    somecontent2: 'content2'
});
```